# YOLOv5: Basic Architecture - Where to find?

Tags: architecture, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

Has anybody come across a legit figure of the basic architecture of YOLOv5 (Ultralytics)? I found the below image in one study, but don't seem to be able to verify whether it's a valid depiction of the base architecture of the model.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This one looks correct for YOLOv5 release v4.0.

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/280#issuecomment-774578839